# Is there anyway to load comma seperated string into a single column in hive?

Tags: hiveql

'TOK_STRINGLITERALSEQUENCE not supported in insert/values' getting this error while loading data into the hive.

when trying to insert a comma-separated string into a single column it is showing error as

> 'TOK_STRINGLITERALSEQUENCE not supported in insert/values'

```
insert into table table_name values('llu'/t'ghf'/t'a,b,c,d'/t'gh,edf,ghu,kjhl'/t'1')
```

/t represents delimiter as tab

while loading data I am getting an error as **'TOK_STRINGLITERALSEQUENCE not supported in insert/values'.**

```
Expected results
col1     col2      col3        col4               col5
llu      ghf       a,b,c,d     gh,edf,ghu,kjhl    1
```

Comment: What version of Hive are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using tab-delimitation for the insert statement. This worked for me in Hive version 1.2.1

```
create table test (col1 STRING, col2 STRING, col3 STRING, col4 STRING, col5 STRING);

insert into table test values('llu','ghf','a,b,c,d','gh,edf,ghu,kjhl','1');

select * from test;
+------------+------------+------------+------------------+------------+--+
| test.col1  | test.col2  | test.col3  |    test.col4     | test.col5  |
+------------+------------+------------+------------------+------------+--+
| llu        | ghf        | a,b,c,d    | gh,edf,ghu,kjhl  | 1          |
+------------+------------+------------+------------------+------------+--+
```

Comment: I used fields terminated by tab while creating table, that is why I am loading values with tab seperated

Comment: @Nageshwarreddy "fields terminated by" refers to how the table's underlying raw data is stored in HDFS. However the syntax for an insert statement almost always follows the SQL grammar set forth by ISO/IEC 9075 and should be the same, regardless of how you decide to store the data. In fact that's one of the core strengths of Hive, you can create an external table on top of data of various formats and just use a common SQL interface to abstract it all away and interact with the data in a raw-file-format-independent manner. I think I'm digressing, did the answer work for you?